# Is it better to use a subquery in the FROM clause, as to minimize the cartesian product?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have 2 tables, Customer and Address, with the following fields each:

```
Customer
========
Id: INT
Name: VARCHAR(25)
Address_Id: INT (FK from Address Table)


Address
=======
Id: INT
Country: VARCHAR(25)
City: VARCHAR(25)
Street: VARCHAR(25)
StreetNumber: INT
```

Suppose I want to receive the address and user details of a user with Id: 15.
Should I use a subquery that minimizes the cartesian product, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM User
    WHERE Id = 15
) as u,
Address a
WHERE a.Id = u.Address_Id;
```

or should I just use the following obvious query?

```
SELECT *
FROM User u, Address a
WHERE u.Id = 15 AND u.Address_Id = a.Id;
```

Comment: Use a `JOIN` instead.

Comment: @Matthew but, unless I am mistaken when one writes: "FROM TableName1, TableName2", that is the most basic form of a join. Were you referring to something more specific (like inner joins that happen first and if you were, why not use a subquery)?

Comment: 'obvious query' - not really - read up on joins

Comment: `FROM table1, table2` results in what's considered a "full" join.  When you do `WHERE table1.Id = table2.fkid` then I would consider that an inner join.  Using `JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fkid` is the idiomatic way of representing a join in SQL.  The goal of using the `JOIN` syntax is to give enough information to the SQL interpreter to do what you want to achieve in the most efficient way possible (by conveying your intent)

Comment: @ImperatorRomanorum the most basic join is using the keyword `JOIN`. This is more readable than the `table1, table2` 25 years old

Comment: @Matthew AFAIK, both syntax are equivalent in term of being efficient. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10308304/8398549)

Comment: @Cid perhaps, I'm not 100% certain about the implementation of various SQL engines (postgres, mysql, mssql, oracle, db2, etc.)

Comment: it heavy depens on MySQL version/optimizer what will happen.. From MySQL 5.7 this query wil be flattened out meaning `SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM User
    WHERE Id = 15
) as u,
Address a
WHERE a.Id = u.Address_Id;` will internal be rewriten and optimized as `SELECT *
FROM User u, Address a
WHERE u.Id = 15 AND u.Address_Id = a.Id;` as MySQL knows both statements will give the same results and avoids having to create a deliverd table.. Before MySQL 5.7 it would create a deliverd table and index it before joining..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a subquery here. You can use

```
SELECT *
FROM User u
JOIN Address a ON u.Address_Id = a.Id
WHERE u.Id = 15;
```

or your query

```
SELECT *
FROM User u, Address a
WHERE u.Id = 15 AND u.Address_Id = a.Id;
```

In both cases the engine will apply the condition `u.Id = 15` as soon as possible - Thus only read one row from the `User` table.